# When working with a form element how would you access what was input into the element to display a message?

Tags: javascript

I have a form 
`<form>
  <input id="input" type="number">
  <input type="submit">
  </form>`
 I want to be able to input a number into the number  and click the submit button and javascript displays a number based on the number submitted.

(My Guess is that this question is very basic but I am pretty knew to javascript.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very *simple* (jquery-less) example of what you might be after:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowANumber() {
            var currentNumber = document.getElementById("input").value;
            var newNumber = currentNumber * 10 // Do something with input
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = newNumber;    
            return false;  // Stop form submit
        }
    </script>
    <form onsubmit="return ShowANumber();">
        <input id="input" type="text"/>
        <input type="submit"/> 
    </form>
    <div>Result: <span id="result"></span></div>
```